# How to update multiple records at once in MS Access 2013?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a database where i register the appointments of the employees. Every appointment has a status (tpi_status). Default it is on: "Wachten op akkoord" (Waiting for agreement).

[image: TBL_PlanningIndicatie]

I use this table in a query. In this query i calculate the weeknumber (Week) and the year (Jaar) and i add the teamname (tcl_hoofd). I use this query data in a form to show me the query information. In this form i'd like to change the status of all records of a certain week at once.

[image: Query]

So for example i select year 2016 and week 39 in my form, i then select a new status in a dropdown and then all records in TBL_PlanningIndicatie of week 39 and year 2016 change to the new status.

Could somebody help me out, i am thinking of a VBA after update script that inserts the new status in the table after i select a new value in the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Make your datasheet form a subform to an unbound main form. On the main form, add a dropdown to select status, and a command button. Get the week from whatever record is selected in the subform (or add a dropdown on the main form to select it). On the button_click, run an update query to do what you want, then refresh the subform.

Comment: Thanks, will try that out tomorrow. Could you tell me how the update query looks like?